# Shorter implementation for this code in Rust

Tags: file, rust, filesystems

Not so long ago, I switched from Python to Rust and started learning it.

I want to try to open a file in read-only, read it and print the data.
But I cannot understand, why I need write data to variable after reading file.

I want make this without buffer (?) string.

Like there:

```py
with open("data.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply [`copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/fn.copy.html) from an `io::Read` (such as a `File`) to an `io::Write` (such as `Stdout`):

```rust
use std::{fs, io};

fn main() {
    let mut file = fs::File::open("/etc/passwd").unwrap();
    let mut stdout = io::stdout();
    io::copy(&mut file, &mut stdout).unwrap();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5048777a11dc1c7f7e7173a371b6fe7e).

Comment: I would lock stdout for faster access.

Comment: You can omit the variables for another ~45bytes less readability.

Answer (score 0):

This [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76797465/9123725) is pretty good. But if you still want shorter code, you can write it like this:

```rust
use std::fs::read;
use std::io::{stdout, Write};

stdout().write_all(&read("/etc/passwd").unwrap()).unwrap();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e5e27253d291e09bcb0a29d39528fa4a)

Comment: However, optimisations aside, this does still read the file content into a new allocation before writing it out; whereas the `copy` approach in my answer avoids all of that.